# Mediawiki: how to insert a <script>-Tag

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, script-tag, javascript-injection

I'd like to insert a flattr image in my mediawiki installation. That requires to insert a `<script>...</script>` section into the header of the html file. I have no clue, where I can insert this, for I can't find a `<head>`-tag in the file `MonoBook.php`. I use the current mediawiki software (1.16.2) and the MonoBook style. Can someone give me a clue where I can insert the required javascript?

Comment: If this helps: I can edit all files on the server (and I am not afraid of doing so).

Comment: for insert "by demand" (different script per page), see [Extension:Gadgets](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a good solution: I enable JavaScript with `$wgUseSiteJs = true;` and insert the flattr js in `MediaWiki:Common.js`.

Comment: This option is usefull only for global Javascrit. To create a different interative illustration at each page, e.g. with,  [D3js](https://d3js.org/), you can use `MediaWiki:Common.js` to include by `mw.loader.load( '/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:D3.v5.min.js&action=raw&ctype=text/javascript' );` ... **But seems be impossible to use it!!**, to draw each different illustration in each page, so it is not useful. There are an alternative?

Comment: A solution (!), see [Extension:Gadgets](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets) and a loadJs-by-gadget [example]( https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-site.js).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert `<script>` tags using the editor, the only way to do so is to use an extension... in my case, I use [WikiScript](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWikiScript).

Comment: This looks like I have to insert the `<wikiscript>` tag in the actual page contents, right? I can't find a page like `MediaWiki:Sidebar` that allows me to insert the `<wikiscript>`-Tag so it will be visible for all users.

Comment: If you need to insert that tag into the sidebar, the easiest option is to edit monobook.php and place the `<script>` tag right there. I did that too for my mediawiki instance. :)

Comment: I can't find a place to add this in `MonoBook.php` anymore (which I used to do). The sidebar I mentioned was just an analogy. I'd like to put the `<script>`-Tag either in a) a file on the server or b) in the wiki database with the wiki web editor on a page that gets loaded as a header for every wiki page.

Comment: @limc The referenced extension is removed.